# Java : binary tree + preorder traversal + recursion + return a result list

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

Small Java question on a preorder traversal of a binary tree, using recursion, with a result list of all the elements returned please.

Looking at the web we can see many result on the use of recursion to traverse a tree. However, they all "just print" the nodes, returning nothing:

https://makeinjava.com/recursive-binary-tree-traversal-algorithm-java-preorder-postorderinorder/

```
public static void preOrderRecursive(Node root) {
    if (null == root) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.printf("%d ", root.data);
    preOrderRecursive(root.left);
    preOrderRecursive(root.right);
}
```

This is a recursive function  but does not return anything

On the other hand, there are many examples where it returns the binary tree as list, but using an iterative way:

```
public List<Integer> preorderIterative(TreeNode root) {
    LinkedList<TreeNode> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> output = new LinkedList<>();
    if (root == null) {
      return output;
    }

    stack.add(root);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      TreeNode node = stack.pollLast();
      output.add(node.val);
      if (node.right != null) {
        stack.add(node.right);
      }
      if (node.left != null) {
        stack.add(node.left);
      }
    }
    return output;
  }
```

This is an iterative function , it does return the result as list

My question is, I am having hard time building a recursive function  which returns the result as list .

What I tried (and not working):

```
 public static List<Integer> preOrderRecursiveWithReturn(TreeNode root) {
        if (null == root) {
            return ???;
        } else {
            return preOrderRecursiveWithReturn(root.left) preOrderRecursiveWithReturn(root.right) ???
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, it is not working.
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper function that takes the output list as extra argument:

```
    // Helper
    private static void preOrderRecursive(Node root, LinkedList<Integer> output) {
        if (null == root) {
            return;
        }
        output.add(root.data);
        preOrderRecursive(root.left, output);
        preOrderRecursive(root.right, output);
    }

    // Actual function that returns the list
    public static LinkedList<Integer> preOrder(Node root) {
        LinkedList<Integer> output = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        preOrderRecursive(root, output);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be not to have the recursive method return the list, but have the recursive method add to a list field.

```
private List<Integer> output;

public static void preOrderRecursive(Node root) {
if (null == root) {
    return;
}
//System.out.printf("%d ", root.data);
list.add(root.data);
preOrderRecursive(root.left);
preOrderRecursive(root.right);
```

}

Comment: This sounds interesting! Upvoting the idea. May I ask if you can share an example? And besides the example, is there a way to have the recursion + return as list?

Comment: well if you return, the list, you will need to either pass it to the recursive method, so that it can be added to, or to take two resulting lists and merge.  Personally I would go for my answer and you do not need to change the methods signature.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do wish to return something, hence having ```List<Integer>``` in the method signature, let me try to come up with something based on what you just said (if you have it handy, please share!)